# Why cant I find consumable and non consumable purchase types in iTunes connect for In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I want to choose a non consumable type, but it only shows free subscription type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Agreements, Tax, and Banking details not requested in iTunes connect for paid applications. See below.
[image]